# How to zoom a pdf with centering?

Tags: printing, pdf

I am using Document Viewer 3.10.3 in Ubuntu 14.04

I want to zoom a pdf and print it to a file (another pdf). I am able to zoom it but the issue I am facing is this :

the pdf is getting zoomed towards right and bottom... but I want to zoom the page equally on all the four sides. (Basically it is not centering)

Just to make my point more clear I have attatched the following images

**Input**

[image: input pdf screenshot]

**Undesired Output**

[image]

If Document Viewer with its print options cant do this job then kindly suggest which other tool can serve the purpose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Well you always have the option to print to another file, instead of directly printing to a printer. In my case I want tp print it to another pfd

Comment: It depends...
 In my case I want to zoom a pdf and save it as another pdf so that I can give the zoomed pdf directly for printing (on paper). It just makes the job of the person whoever is printing a lot easier if the only work he has to do is to just print rather than worry about how to scale the document for better viewing. I hope I answered your doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to crop every page of a pdf, then I suggest [Briss](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/files/). It can not only crop a pdf but also produce more pages from a single page.

It is a simple yet effective pdf cropper.

To install,

- download the `briss-0.9.tar.gz` file,
- Unzip it somewhere of your choice,
- Create a script (I named it `briss.sh`) with the following content:

  ```
  cd /path/to/briss/folder/briss
  java -Xmx256m -Djava.library.path=. -jar briss-0.9.jar
  ```

Make it executable (right-click on nautilus, permissions).

- Create a `briss.desktop` launcher in `/home/username/.local/share/applications`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

  [Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0
  Type=Application
  Terminal=false
  Exec=/path/to/briss/folder/briss.sh
  Name=Briss
  Icon=/path/to/briss/icon/briss.jpg
  ```

Change the Exec line and the Icon line accordingly (I created an icon myself).

- Make the `.desktop` file executable.
- Run it as any other application.

Comment: Can you add details on how to crop the pdf?

Comment: Fantastic works perfectly... this is better than what I wanted.

Comment: @RegisteredUser It is very simple, I just downloaded and unzipped  briss, navigate to the location where you did unzip and then type in the terminal          java -jar briss-0.9.jar         Once you do this drag your document to the application and rest is self explanatory...